# How to switch between Components in React.js

Tags: reactjs

So I am building a React app and got I think a decent idea pf whay I am doing. But I am looking to find how I can switch between components. Each component is its own individual js file.

App.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import MainPage from './mainpage'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Welcome to Comix Nation </h1>
      <MainPage />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

---

mainpage.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

import CreateAccount from './createaccount.js'
import LogIn from './login.js'
import MainMenu from './mainmenu.js'

class MainPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            currentPage: 'login'
        };
    }

    getPage(currentPage){
        const page ={
            mainmenu: <MainMenu />,
            createaccount: <CreateAccount />,
            login: <LogIn />
        };

        return page[currentPage]
    }

    switchPage(currentPage){
        this.setState({currentPage});
    };

    render(){
      return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <MainMenu switchPages={this.switchPage}/>
            </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default MainPage;
```

---

mainmenu.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class MainMenu extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {page: 'none'}
  }

  handleSelection(pageSelection){
    this.props.switchPage(pageSelection);
  }

  render(){
      return (
      <div>
        <h2 onClick={()=> this.handleSelection('createaccount')}>Click to create new account</h2>
        <h2>Click to log in</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MainMenu;
```

The idea is that I can click on either the create or login and get the appropriate js file to render.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: Use routing 
https://reactjs.org/community/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

so, from reading your code it sounds like you want to do routing (judging from your naming convention at least). There are a number of [routing libraries](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) you can use to render different pages if you want to use that. If you just want to switch out components, you've almost got it

```
class MainPage extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        currentPage: 'login'
    };
}


switchPage(currentPage){
    this.setState({currentPage});
};

render(){
  return (
    <div>
        <div>
         {
            this.state.currentPage === 'login' &&
            <Login/>
         }
         {
            this.state.currentPage === 'MainMenu' &&
            <MainMenu/>
         }
         {
            this.state.currentPage === 'SignUp' &&
            <SignUp/>
         }
        </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The way react reads this is `true` and `render this component` some people prefer to use a ternary and return null but this is cooler imho

Comment: Thank you to everyone for responding. I will be looking over all this and def see which one I can get to work.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, if you are trying to avoid react-router-dom you can implement this system fairly easy.

```
this.state = {
currentComponent: "",
}
```

this will allow you to keep track of what component is suppose to show. Put this in your controllers state.

```
showComponent = (component) => {
      this.setState({currentComponent: component})
    }
```

Put this in your main controller file, where you import your components that you will use.

Then you set up your components to display depending what is sent in.

```
let checkCurrentComponent = this.state.currentComponent;
```

Make a variable to check for easy checking.

```
{checkCurrentComponent === "topicList" ? (
              <TopicTitles
                showComponent={this.showComponent}
              />
            ) : checkCurrentComponent === "author" ? (
              <TopicData
                showComponent={this.showComponent}
              />
            ) : checkCurrentComponent === "commentForm" ? (
              <CommentForm }
                showComponent={this.showComponent}
              />
            ): null}
```

Then in your components you can use that function to pass in the name. Here is how I like to do that.

```
const handleCommentForm = (e, component) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.showComponent(component);
  }
```

This will be at the top of my stateless function.
will bring up my comment form.

Then the button..

```
<button 
     className="btn btn-outline-none"
     onClick={e => handleCommentForm(e, "commentForm")}
          >
        Add Comment
 </button>
```